# Vagrant did not install Apache2 nor php

Tags: php, apache2, vagrant, puphpet

I just created a configuration file (it's a zip actually) for my vm on puphpet.com, downloaded the zip, extracted it. Then I run `vagrant up` in the folder where is located the `vagrantfile`. The vm is correctly setup under virtualbox, it runs well and the shared folders are working.

However when I access my vm from the host, using `127.0.0.1:7893` it displays : `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4`. Which is weired since I checked both `install php` and `install apache` on puphpet.
I decided to verify their existance on the vm : `which apache2`, `whereis php` etc.

Nothing was returned.

So appearently `php` and `apache2` have not been installed, even though the `config.yaml`  file (that I created on puphpet) did specify to install both php and apache2.

At this point, I don't really know what to do (I'm new to php/vagrant/puphpet) :

- should I install them myself on the vm with apt-get ?
- ??

EDIT: during the installation process (vagrant up), I get errors like :

```
Err http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64 am
d64 3.2.51-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Fetched 238 kB in 1s (167 kB/s)
Failed to fetch http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers
-3.2.0-4-common_3.2.51-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
```

EDIT2: I 'solved' the problem by using a differents virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

> EDIT: during the installation process (vagrant up), I get errors like : ....

Check that you packages db in VM is up to date.
just run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then try again with apache2 and php installation.

Comment: Thank you. Updating `apt-get` fixed all my issues.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the default config:

```
[01:26 PM]-[vagrant@packer-virtualbox]-[~]
$ php -v
PHP 5.5.10-1~dotdeb.1 (cli) (built: Mar  6 2014 18:55:59)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

Everything looks to be fine on my end.

A couple of things:

- You can access the VM from your browser using the IP address you chose during initial config.
- Looks like your main issue is that you couldn't connection to the Debian repos. Are you behind a firewall?

To try again, do:

```
$ vagrant destroy
$ rm -rf .vagrant
$ vagrant up
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems when I opted for CentOS.
Where did the choosing Debian, the problems stopped occur.